# Finding the meaning for the names of Linux constants

Tags: linux

Linux constants are abbreviations, and for a newcomer, it is very hard to guess what they mean. Often there's no description in documentation for what they stand for, e.g., `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH` and many others.

Is there a resource, like a dictionary or list, to find all those abbreviations explained?

Comment: What variables are you talking about?

Comment: for example  `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH ` and many others

Comment: These aren't variables, but come from libc constants ( eg https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Permission-Bits.html )

Comment: Did you see that expression by itself somewhere? Without any context? Or did you just remove the context yourself before posting this question?

Comment: @MarkAmbrazhevich, if you did a google search for those names , then your question may have been unnecessary

Comment: Instead of googling for those, grep for them `grep -rw S_IRUSR /usr/include` => `/* Read by owner.  */` (first hit).

Comment: And while there's no 'great unified dictionary', the GNU libc manual has a nice [summary of library facilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Library-Summary.html) which contain all those macros and much more (macros, system calls, library functions, global variables). You'd be better served if you make yourself a one-page html version of the GNU libc manual that you could just grep through, instead of compulsively googling and getting all kind of crappy answers from forums and Q&A sites like this ;-)

Comment: @mosvy, that what i was looking for! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

There is no Grand Unified Dictionary for tersely abbreviated constants, but a web search can provide you much of what you seek. For example, a search on **S_IRUSR** revealed the first two results to explain its meaning at  https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Permission-Bits.html and http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html, both of which also provided explanations of **S_IWUSR**, **S_IRGRP**, **S_IWGRP**, **S_IROTH**, and **S_IWOTH**.